# Swift MapKit annotations slow annotation loading

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I've over 1000 different annotations that are shown on a MKMapView and depending on where the user is (visibleMapRect) loads in a new set of annotations based on `region.center`. The problem I'm facing is the MKMapView becomes slow at loading in the annotations

I've tried separating out the annotation types into separate loading methods and calling each one separately on a serial queue and it still loads in the annotations really slow (several seconds)

The method below is called from `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {}`

```
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: self.map.centerCoordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0, longitudeDelta: 0))
            
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "reload-annotations", attributes: .background)
            
            queue.async(group: group) {
                self.firstViewModel.load(coordinates: region.center)
            }
            queue.async(group: group) {
                self.secondViewModel.load(coordinates: region.center)
            }
            queue.async(group: group) {
                self.thirdViewModel.load(coordinates: region.center)
            }
            
            group.notify(queue: queue) {
                
                let annotations = self.map.annotations

                for annotation in self.firstViewModel.data {
                    if !annotations.contains(where: { $0.title == annotation.title }) {
DispatchQueue.main.async {                      
self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
                    }
                }
                for annotation in self.secondViewModel.data {
                    if !annotations.contains(where: { $0.title == annotation.title }) {
DispatchQueue.main.async {  
                        self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
                    }
                }
                for annotation in self.thirdViewModel.data {
                    if !annotations.contains(where: { $0.title == annotation.title }) {
DispatchQueue.main.async {  
                        self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: One of the constraints is that clustering cannot be used. I've since shifted the check for annotation back into the viewModel (only add it to the array if it doesn't exist instead of clearing out the array) - That's improved the loading speed however, I know there's more performance to be had!

Comment: That's a large number of annotations if you don't want to cluster them! No wonder the performance is low. Please share your custom annotation view code to see if/how you can make it lighter. Also, when user pans the map, are removing or keeping the annotations outside the visible area?

Comment: @Asteroid - I managed to solve the issue by shifting the annotation loading logic into the relevant view models. On the thread successfully loading I simply removed and add the annotations back in. It's a manual process instead of relying on MapKit API's.

Comment: Measure actually loading and separately measure adding annotations to the mapView. I have the same amount and adding to the map is really fast. (Configuring Callouts slowed things down, but I'm using my own callouts now)